# How to install i3wm window manage on centos7

Tags: centos, software-installation, i3

I want setup i3wm on centos. I try download rpm file i3 in rpmfind.net but two package (i3-doc <-> i3-wm) have interdependent. I try search google but no answer: How to use i3 on CentOS 7 with Gnome?

*** Update 02/03/2017 ***
I have successfully installed.
Thanks Pavel Salin and Toebe Daniel. Yet you still can not do it like me, I want detailed instructions for many others if encountered.
First, you must have EPEL repositories

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
```

Add DNF stack repositor

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/dnf-stack-el7.repo
[dnf-stack-el7]
name=Copr repo for dnf-stack-el7 owned by @rpm-software-management
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-stack-el7/epel-7-\$basearch/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-stack-el7/pubkey.gpg
enabled=1
enabled_metadata=1
EOF
```

Then install the following commands

```
1) yum install -y dnf dnf-plugins-core
2) dnf copr enable admiralnemo/i3wm-el7
```

And now follow as guided [admiralnemo](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/admiralnemo/i3wm-el7/)

- There is another way that you add the repository directly into centos

  > sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo
  >   https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/admiralnemo/i3wm-el7/repo/epel-7/admiralnemo-i3wm-el7-epel-7.repo

Answer (score 2):

The urls for dnf repo has changed.  Please use below snippet.

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/dnf-stack-el7.repo
[dnf-stack-el7]
name=Copr repo for dnf-stack-el7 owned by @rpm-software-management
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-centos/epel-7-x86_64/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rpm-software-management/dnf-centos/pubkey.gpg
enabled=1
enabled_metadata=1
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a copr repo: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/admiralnemo/i3wm-el7/

To use copr repos see: https://fedorahosted.org/copr/wiki/HowToEnableRepo

Since Centos I believe still uses `yum` in place of the newer `dnf` that is in fedora/RedHat now... Use the yum instructions...

Comment: Yes, I knew a copr repo before that but I run command: '# yum copr enable user/project ' or '# dnf copr enable user/project ' display `No such command: copr. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help`, althought I had install `dnf` and `yum-plugin-copr`. I tried everything before I put this question.

Comment: Ok what version of CentOS are you using? I'll set up a vm and figure it out

Comment: @DanielToeble Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

Answer (score 0):

I also just started with CentOS and new to it's repo and package management system, have the same issue.
On the page about i3wm there is mentioned how to "enable" repo, but first of all you have to add it (assume that dnf, dnf-plugins-core installed) whatever:

```
1) sudo yum install -y dnf dnf-plugins-core
2) sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/admiralnemo/i3wm-el7/repo/epel-7/admiralnemo-i3wm-el7-epel-7.repo
```

After that all should go smoothly and you will be able to install all according admiralnemo/i3wm-el7

How to - Adding, Enabling, and Disabling a DNF Repository
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_DNF_Repositories.html

Comment: Further my reply I reccomend to install Xorg in next way:
`yum groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Desktop Platform"`
it's allowed to miss some packages.

Comment: Yes, I installed it. I'm using Gnome Enviroment on CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

With the help from https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/94vknq/install_i3_from_centos_minimal_iso/ and https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/admiralnemo/i3wm-el7/ this is how I installed **i3 Window Manager** in **CentOS 7.6.1810**,

**01.** Issue the following commands,

```
$ yum install -y epel-release
$ yum clean all && yum update -y && yum upgrade -y
$ yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-drv-vmware xorg-x11-drv-vmmouse xorg-x11-drv-evdev mesa-dri-drivers xorg-x11-xinit-session xterm
$ yum install -y dejavu-sans-fonts dejavu-sans-mono-fonts dejavu-serif-fonts i3 i3status lightdm
$ systemctl set-default graphical.target
$ systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

**02.** Select **i3** from the top right and log in to the server,

[image]

**03.** For the first time login, it'll configure **i3** (press enter twice if the default configuration is okay),

[image]

[image]

That's all. Enjoy!